# In DDEV how to automatically use custom shell config inside docker container?

Tags: ddev

In lieu of manually setting up my dotfiles (.bashrc, .inputrc, .vim & .vimrc etc) inside the docker container that DDEV creates... isn't there a way to automatically do this from the ddev config?  I swear I saw this somewhere (maybe a blog post?) and I've been looking through https://ddev.readthedocs.io and websearching but can't find it described anywhere.  Do I need to do `docker cp ...` or is there a `ddev` way?

Comment: This wasn't a bad question, and I'm really glad it's here, because you're not the only one not to know this is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can provide custom in-web-container configuration using homeadditions, see [docs](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/extend/in-container-configuration/#in-container-home-directory-configuration). You can either add new configuration (anything you want in your home directory) per-project (by putting in your project's .ddev/homeadditions) or globally (by putting in the global ~/.ddev/homeadditions).

There's a blog example of doing this (from before you could do it globally in v1.15+) showing setting up oh-my-zsh, https://www.ddev.com/ddev-local/oh-my-zsh-using-custom-commands-and-other-goodies-to-add-to-ddev/

Comment: `.ddev/homeadditions`!  Can't believe I missed that (though I guess it'd be harder to believe it wasn't available or documented).  Thanks <3

Comment: Would love to have suggestions on how to make that more "findable" in the docs. Of course, it's impossible to read everything, or remember what the meaning of something is when you need it.

Comment: I searched for this with the term "shell config" which returns no results.  The "home directory configuration" though it makes sense as dotfiles go in a users home directory didn't correlate in my mind with what I as looking for so I looked right past it.